# Documentation for Fluoride bluetooth stack

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I'm working on BLE using Fluoride stack which is open-source. Is there any documentation or any notes that would help me to understand the architecture of Fluoride stack? Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Not really. It was called Bluedroid before and was written by Broadcom before it was taken over by Google for Android. You have some info at https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth of the overall structure, but documentation is lacking. Reading the source code is the best idea I can give.

If there is any particular part you're interested in (GATT, SMP, L2CAP, connection establishment, Java layer) etc, feel free to ask.